# numpy.savetxt- Save one column as int and the rest as floats?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, text-files, number-formatting

**The Problem**

So I have a 2D array (151 rows, 52 columns) I'd like to save as a text file using np.savetxt. However, I want the first column's numbers to save as integers (1950, 1951, etc) while the rest of the data saves as precision 5 (4 if rounded) floating point numbers (2.7419, 2.736, etc). I can't figure out how to do this.

**The Code**

When I print the first 4 rows & 3 columns of the output of the array, it looks like this.

[[ 1950.         2.7407     2.7396]

[ 1951.          2.7419     2.736 ]

[ 1952.          2.741      2.7374]

[ 1953.          2.7417     2.7325]]

When I use the following...

```
np.savetxt('array.txt',data,fmt="%1.4f")
```

The array saves the first column as a precision 5 floating point numbers like the rest of the data (1950.0000, 1951.0000, etc). When I try to specify different formats as such...

```
np.savetxt('array.txt',data,fmt="%i %1.4f")
```

I get the following error: "ValueError: fmt has wrong number of % formats:  %i %1.4f"

**The Question**

Is there a way I say save the first column as integers and the rest of the columns as floating point numbers?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`data` has 3 columns, so you need supply 3 `'%format'`s.  For example:

```
np.savetxt('array.txt', data, fmt='%i %1.4f %1.4f')
```

should work.  If you have a lot more than 3 columns, you can try something like:

```
np.savetxt('array.txt', data, fmt=' '.join(['%i'] + ['%1.4f']*N))
```

where `N` is the number of columns needing float formatting.

Comment: Second solution was exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Does a 'delimiter' parameter work with the second solution? I tried using a tab delimiter, but it does not work.

Comment: @TomKurushingal, per [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html), if you use a multi-format string, like above, the `delimiter` keyword argument is ignored: "A single format (%10.5f), a sequence of formats, or a multi-format string, e.g. ‘Iteration %d – %10.5f’, in which case delimiter is ignored."  You could (a) use `"\t"` for the `str.join` or (b) supply a list of formats without `join`ing and then use `delimiter="\t"`.

Answer (score 3):

As @wflynny, but with out `join`:

```
np.savetxt('array.txt', data, fmt='%i'+' %1.4f'*N)
```

Answer (score 0):

your `fmt` parameter needs to have the the same number of `%` as the columns you are trying ot format.  You are trying to format 3 columns but only giving it 2 formats.

Try changing your `np.savetxt(...)` to

```
np.savetxt('array.txt',data,fmt="%i %1.4f %1.4f")
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the columns of my datamatrix were automatically concatenated, what I didnt want.
To keep the format with separate columns you can add a separator ';'.
The solution will look like:

```
np.savetxt('array.txt',data,fmt='%i' + ';%1.4f' * 4)
```

p.s. I was saving as .csv